# What is the difference between cups-filters and foomatic-filters?

Tags: printing, cups

I tried googling the question `What is the difference between cups-filters + foomatic-filters` but I could not find anything helpful.  The most descriptive result was from a mailing list but did not seem to answer my question.

In (k)ubuntu these 2 packages are mutually exclusive and I am trying to work out which to install.

In case it is relevant CUPS is already installed.

Comment: '+' is not always synonymous with 'and'. I would have replaced both cases but the second was in a quote.

Comment: You might get some info from OpenPrinting where for  [cups-filters](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/openprinting/cups-filters) it says *From CUPS 1.6.0 on, this package is required for using printer drivers with CUPS under Linux.*.  See also the [foomatic](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/openprinting/database/foomatic) page.

Answer (score 3):

The [last release of foomatic-filters is 4.017 dated July 2012](https://www.openprinting.org/download/foomatic/). Since then [foomatic-filters have been included in cups-filters as "foomatic-rip"](https://lists.gt.net/gentoo/user/288187#288187):

> Some time ago the cups-filters maintainers took over maintainership of the
>   foomatic-filters part for CUPS as well, and integrated it cleanly into cups-
>   filters. That's the reason for the blocker; recent cups-filters contain the
>   newest foomatic code available. The former separate foomatic-filters package
>   is now unmaintained.

So nowadays the only relevant package is cups-filters, which provides foomatic-rip.

Answer (score -1):

Both CUPS and Foomatic are printer drivers.

Since are both drivers, they are mutually excluded each other.